# SQLiteException no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

I am writing an SQL query like this:

```
Cursor data = db.query(WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_TABLE_NAME, null, WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_GROUP_COLUMN+"="+params[0], null, null, null, null);
```

And it's producing the following error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(620): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Friends: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM ww_friend WHERE friend_group=Friends
```

There is no column called Friends, I want to retrieve the rows where the friend_group column has the value Friends. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Friends` should be quoted to illustrate its a string value and not an object name

Comment: have you tried surrounding `params[0]` with single quotes (')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to surround Friend value with quote :

```
Cursor data = db.query(WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_TABLE_NAME, null, WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_GROUP_COLUMN+"='"+params[0]+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

PS: be sure to escape dangerous characters from param[0] when you do like this to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: Thanks it's working now (I can't accept yet as it's too soon).  Thanks for the tip about escaping.  I always escape & use parameterised queries in PHP, are there equivalent functions in Java/Android?

Comment: Hum, I don't know an equivalent method for that. But it easy to implements. Be sure to unescape quotes and always surround all your values (integer too) with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that *"Friends"* is a value, so you must enclose it within quotes.

Try this:

```
Cursor data = db.query(WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_TABLE_NAME, null, WhereWolfOpenHelper.FRIEND_GROUP_COLUMN+"=\""+params[0]+"\"", null, null, null, null);
```